# Contact Form 7 Redirect Based on Drop-Down Selection

Tags: javascript, wordpress, drop-down-menu

Been searching for an answer for this across the web.  Everything I find doesn't seem to help.  I know this is totally wrong too - I don't know enough about JS to get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

4 options in a dropdown in Contact Form7 (on wp site).  Depending on which option chosen, redirect to the appropriate paypal payment page.

Here is JS added to page in WP.

```
function paypalRedirect() {

        if (document.getElementsByName("eventPackage")[0].selected) {
            location.href = 'http://www.test1.com';}
        if (document.getElementsByName("eventPackage")[1].selected) {
            location.href = 'http://www.test2.com';}
        if (document.getElementsByName("eventPackage")[2].selected) {
            location.href = 'http://www.test3.com';}
        if (document.getElementsByName("eventPackage")[3].selected) {
            location.href = 'http://www.test4.com';}   
    };
```

And here is the additional setting in Contact Form 7:

```
on_sent_ok: "paypalRedirect();"
```

Everything works fine witht the form, I just can't get the redirect to work.  And I don't see any errors in the console...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Contact Form 7 will abolish the on_sent_ok hook:

> Note: The method using on_sent_ok hook is no longer recommended. This function is scheduled to be abolished by the end of 2017. (https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/)
>   Thats why we need a different approach with DOM events (https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

Contact Form 7 gives an example for the redirect:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://www.example.com';
}, false );
```

I would also be interested in how we can combine the dom redirect with a dropdown option